# Why css-loader/style-loader throws unexpected character # error?

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I took the [Webpack](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) tutorial from Angular.io and started to upgrade to Webpack 2 following the official and a [not official](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2016/10/moving-to-webpack-2/) guide.

I met the error below:

> ERROR in ./public/css/styles.css
>       Module parse failed: DashboardDelivery.Host.Ui.Spa\public\css\styles.css Unexpected
>   character '#' (3:16)
>       You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>       | ﻿body
>       | {
>       |     background: #0147A7;
>       |     color: #fff;
>       | }

- I don't get what the problem is
- if the file empty then it throws an error where text.Foreach is unknown function
- if only an empty body{} in the css file then webpack complains body is not defined

Basically, doesn't matter what I do there is always an issue and the character related is the most strange. What I'm missing here?

webpack.common.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/app/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/app/vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/app/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
          {
              test: /\.ts$/,
              use: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
          },
          {
              test: /\.html$/,
              use: 'html-loader'
          },
          {
              test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
              use: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
          },
          {
              test: /\.css$/,
              exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
              use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                  {
                      fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
                      loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap',
                      publicPath: "/dist"
                  })
          },
          {
              test: /\.css$/,
              include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
              use: 'raw-loader'
          }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
          name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
      }),

      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: 'src/index.html'
      }),

    ]
};
```

webpack.dev.js

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },

    plugins: [
      new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
    ],

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'minimal'
    }
});
```

style.css

```
body 
{
    background: #0147A7;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few grinding hours to find answer there is an answer... ExtractTextPlugin doesn't work with the new use syntax. Here is the [blog](https://medium.com/@u_glow/things-i-learned-while-upgrading-to-webpack-2-418b99965cbf#.644ciq5yb) I found the suggestion, and here is the bug [ticket](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/275).